# Vulkan Buffer Size is different that what I passed in the CreateBuffer struct

Tags: c++, vulkan

[image]

I'm trying to Create a Uniform buffer with the Vulkan Memory Allocator Library and I recently ran into a weird Issue.

As You can see the Buffer Size that I pass as a Parameter in the CreateInfo is 16 (You can confirm that in the Log Below) but the final allocation size in the VmaAllocationInfo Struct (m_allocInfo) that stores the memory related Information is 64 (See the Log Again).
Does anyone know why this happens and how to Fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "fix" this as it's per design. GPUs, and as such Vulkan implementations, have different requirements e.g. for buffer sizes and alignments. The fact that you get a 64 byte large buffer although you only requested 16 bytes means that the Vulkan implementation you're on simply has 64 bytes as it's minimum buffer size requirement.